# Access to a C# object in a Javascript script

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I'm working in a C# project. In a view, I need to work with a script (in Javascript) provided by my teacher. 
First of all, my view receive a List. For example: [location1,location2,location3]. Location has latitude and longitude parametres. 
In my Javascript, I have the function "L.marker([x,y]).addTo(mapa).on('click', onClick);". What I want is to pass location1.longitude and location1.latitude as parametrs of the marker function. How can I do it?

```
@model List<SistemaGestion.Helpers.JsonApiGoogle.Location>

(some HTML code)

<script>
(code)
       for (var coordenadas in Model) {
            L.marker([coordenadas.latitude, coordenadas.longitude]).addTo(mapa).on('click', onClick);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You could use something like json.net/newtonsoft to stringify your c# object into your script tag.

Comment: Can you explain with details? ....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to serialize to JSON. I'm replacing your List of objects with a simple list of strings just for simplicity's sake. But it should work with just about any data structure (with some caveats, like with recursive nesting)

```
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@model List<string>

@{ // this is running server-side
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model); 
}

<script> // this will run client-side, 
    //but the @Html.Raw(json) will be "injecting" into the client side script.
    var array = @Html.Raw(json); 
    console.log(array);
</script>
```

The Html.Raw is important, otherwise it will escape " as &quot; and that sort of thing.

What this looks like if you view source in the browser:

```
var array = ["hello","world","this","is","a","test"];
```